# Error during the boot process in Debian Wheezy: udev (version 175)

Tags: debian, udev, debian-wheezy

During the boot process, it appear this error:

```
startpar: service(s) returned failure: udev
```

It seems to be a problem for the "mounting" of the webcam device:

```
dmesg | grep udev
uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 UVC VGA WebCam (13d3:5710)
```

I have an Asus X53S.

I've also looked for a solution in [bugs.debian.org](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=udev;package=wheezy), but I just notice that udev has lots of issues in Wheezy.

Comment: Could you include more detail?  Like, relevant `/var/log/syslog` parts?  Have you tried starting `udevd` yourself (i.e., in a terminal)?

Comment: If I start `udevd` in my terminal, the command goes in a loop.

in `/var/log/syslog` never appear udev or other similar things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an error reporting to Debian (but nobody answer to me directly), I decided to upgrade my kernel from `3.0.0-3-amd64` to the newest `3.2.0-3-amd64`, and the problem during the boot seems to be disappear. Now the webcam works well. The problem with ***udev*** seems to be fixed with this kernel version.